# Executing generated commands in bash

Tags: bash

I want to run a series of bash commands generated by a Python script. The commands are of the form `export foo="bar"` and `alias foo=bar`. They must modify the environment of the current process.

This works great:

```
$(./generate_commands.py)
```

until an export command contains a space e.g. `export x="a b"`. This generates an error, and only `"a` is exported (quotes included).

Currently I'm working around this by outputting generate_commands to a temporary file and sourcing that, but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Can you show what you're doing exactly?

Comment: Hopefully I made the question a bit clearer.

Comment: "They must modify the environment of the current process." That's not going to work. If you're currently running in `python`, then, regardless of the exact syntax or method of doing so, running `bash` in order to evaluate the commands you generated will start a separate process, which by definition cannot influence the environment variables of its parent process.

Comment: @twalberg no, it already does work, the question is whether it can work more elegantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
./generate_commands | bash
```

This will pipe the output of the script as input to `bash`

Edit:

To allow for variables to be visible in the current shell, you need to source the output:

```
source <(./generate_commands)
```

or

```
. <(./generate_commands)
```

Comment: Apologies for not making it clearer the first time around: the commands are mostly of the form `export x=y` and must modify the environment of the current process.

Comment: @MichaelPlatings then sourcing is your only way to go, everything else will only modify the subshell environment, answer edited

Comment: I guess that's the answer, thanks. Next problem:
`print 'export ' + key + '="' + value + '"'
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Comment: That looks like a python error. Have you executed this manually in a shell, outside of the script? Also try adding `set -x` or `#!/bin/bash -x` to view the debug statements made by `bash` script so that you can see what the lines being executed are, and which, if any, are failing.

Comment: Yes it's a python error. Executing it outside the script gives the same error. I guess python just doesn't play nicely with this method. In case it gives any insight, with `bash -x` I get the following output:
`++ ./generate_commands.py`
`+ . /dev/fd/63`
`++ echo -ne '\033]0;michael@comp: /my/working/dir\007'`

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP's problem is

```
cmd="export x=\"a b\""
${cmd}
```

does not work, but

```
export x="a b"
```

works. My way around this is

```
export x="a"
echo $x
x+=" b"
echo $x
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but `cmd2="x+=\" b\""` `${cmd2}` generates an error `bash: x+=": command not found`

Comment: @MichaelPlatings Did you put them in a script? it worked on my machine though :)

Comment: Yes. It works when typing the commands directly, but the error occurs running the commands from a script.